# query xml using xpath in java

Tags: java, xml, dom, xml-parsing

I am trying to make some queries on huge XML file using xpath in java, here is my code :

```
         DocumentBuilderFactory docBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
         docBuilderFactory.setNamespaceAware(true);

         DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
         Document document = docBuilder.parse(new File("test.xml"));

         XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();

         String xPath = "/*/*[@id='ABCD']/*/*";

         XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile(xPath);
         NodeList result = (NodeList)expr.evaluate(document, XPathConstants.NODESET);
```

The last line of the code takes a lot of time i dont know why, withtout this line program finishes in 1 sec and with it in 40 secs.
I also tried XOM which is also not working.
What is the alternative to make faster queries in a huge XML file in java?

Answer (score 0):

Use SAX, not DOM. Because SAX requires much less memory than DOM, because SAX does not construct an internal representation (tree structure) of the XML data, as a DOM does. Instead, SAX simply sends data to the application as it is read; your application can then do whatever it wants to do with the data it sees.

For details read.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/sax/index.html

Comment: to query I am using xpath which i think is in turn using DOM, is SAX faster then Xpath?

Comment: the problem is I am trying to write a general solution for reading XML file and I may not know the tag names in advance but the structure will be same,that is why I have used * as regular expression in xpath and in SAX i will have to define a java class with class members as tag names so this is not going to work for me.